# this.$http.get seems doesn't work vue-resource

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

uses vue 2.1.10 vue-resource 1.3.4 to fetch the data:

```
    const app = new Vue({
    el: '#UserController',
    data:{
      users : [],
    },
    methods:{
      fetchUser: function(){
          this.$http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/api/users', function(data){
              this.$set('users',data)
          })
      }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.fetchUser()
    }
});
```

but in the end

users has no value.

Comment: The arguments to `Vue.set` are `(target, key, value)`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set.

Comment: Try `this.users = data`

Comment: I tried this.users = data ,,, doesn't work ! :| :(

Comment: Your URL of .../api/api/.. seems suspicious

Comment: URL s fine works correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue-resource is a promise based API.
The syntax for the get request should be

```
this.$http.get('/someUrl')
    .then(response => { 
        // get body data
        this.someData = response.body; 
    }, err => { 
        // error callback 
    });
```

Since you have initialized `users: [ ]` in the data option , no need to use `Vue.$set` you can directly assign the value using `this.users = data`

So do it like this:

```
fetchUser: function(){
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/api/users')
        .then((data) => {
            this.users = data;
        }, err => {
            // handle error 
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     const app = new Vue({
        el: '#UserController',
        data:{
          users : [],
        },
        methods:{
          fetchUser: function(){
              var self = this;
              this.$http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/api/users', function(data){
                  self.$set(self,'users',data)
              })
          }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.fetchUser()
        }
    });
```

Check variable scope. Set pointer to "this" like "self".